# Website responsiveness - Iphone needs double click for a link to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, responsive-design

I am getting this strange issue while testing our webpage on IPhone. There is a "Back to Top" link in bottom right corner of the screen which works very well on all desktop browsers as well on Android phones. But when we test it on IPhone, we have to click that link twice to get it work.

You can see the stage site here: http://www.maverick-eng.com.php53-14.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/

Please advise.

Thanks
Sumit

Comment: Put the relevant code within the OP.  Never rely solely on an external link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things here:

```html
<a href="#top">Back to top of page</a>
```

Or Use JavaScript

```js
/* You can set the scrollTop */

$('html,body').scrollTop(0);

/* Or if you want a little animation instead of a snap to the top: */

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
```